# spring-boot redis : How to invalidate all sessions of a user?

Tags: java, spring, session, redis

I'm new to redis. I've followed this tutorial to use HttpSession with redis.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot.html

Now my application has 'Sign out from all devices' option. When that is clicked how do I remove or invalidate all sessions of that user?

Also when the user changes his password, how do I invalidate all his sessions except the current session?

**Edit:**

I tried using Session Registry.

```
@Autowired
private FindByIndexNameSessionRepository sessionRepository;

@Autowired
FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<? extends ExpiringSession> sessions;

@RequestMapping(value = "/logoutalldevices", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Response test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry(sessionRepository);

    Collection<? extends ExpiringSession> usersSessions = sessions
            .findByIndexNameAndIndexValue(FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME, "myUserId")
            .values();

    usersSessions.forEach((temp) -> {
        String sessionId = temp.getId();
        // sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(sessionId);
        SessionInformation info = sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(sessionId);
        info.expireNow();
    });

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

But it is not removing the session from redis db or invalidating it. though it's adding a new attribute to the session named 'sessionAttr:org.springframework.session.security.SpringSessionBackedSessionInformation.EXPIRED' with value true. I can see this new key value pair  in redis db using redis client when I do

`HGETALL 'sessionid'`

**Edit**

I tried deleting the session manually from redis db using redistemplate.

```
@Autowired
RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;

---------

redisTemplate.delete("spring:session:sessions:" + sessionId);
redisTemplate.delete("spring:session:sessions:expires:" + sessionId);
```

This almost works. It deletes the value from redis db, but not the key.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "spring:session:sessions:25635a14-a4f1-4aa1-bf5a-bc20f972eec7"
2) "spring:session:sessions:expires:25635a14-a4f1-4aa1-bf5a-bc20f972eec7"
3) "spring:session:index:org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME:1"
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall spring:session:sessions:25635a14-a4f1-4aa1-bf5a-bc20f972eec7
1) "lastAccessedTime"
2) "\xac\xed\x00\x05sr\x00\x0ejava.lang.Long;\x8b\xe4\x90\xcc\x8f#\xdf\x02\x00\x01J\x00\x05valuexr\x00\x10java.lang.Number\x86\xac\x95\x1d\x0b\x94\xe0\x8b\x02\x00\x00xp\x00\x00\x01[R'\x15\xc1"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

It deleted all other key values pairs inside the session except lastAccessedTime time.

Also one weird this is, this is the log I see in redis monitor when `redisTemplate.delete("key")` is executed:

```
1491731944.899711 [0 127.0.0.1:62816] "DEL" "spring:session:sessions:25635a14-a4f1-4aa1-bf5a-bc20f972eec7"
1491731944.899853 [0 127.0.0.1:62816] "DEL" "spring:session:sessions:expires:25635a14-a4f1-4aa1-bf5a-bc20f972eec7"
```

If I copy and paste the above two commands to redis-client and execute, the keys are deleted. I do not see keys when I execute `keys *` anymore. I wonder why the key is not getting deleted when its deleted using `RedisTemplate`

```
127.0.0.1:6379> "DEL" "spring:session:sessions:25635a14-a4f1-4aa1-bf5a-bc20f972eec7"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> "DEL" "spring:session:sessions:expires:25635a14-a4f1-4aa1-bf5a-bc20f972eec7"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "spring:session:index:org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME:1"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: can you share your spring security configuration?

Comment: I haven't set any configuration. Just added spring-boot-starter-security dependency. That's it. Do I need to add something?

Comment: you commented `// sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(sessionId);` that should work fine. What happened in your case?

Comment: I tried it, that didn't work.

Comment: Would the `sessionStatus.setComplete()` work for your case?

Comment: i am using `spring-session-data-redis:2.7.0`, the session key and value can be deleted by `redisTemplate` now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would like to know you that **`you are following the correct path`** for invalidating the user sessions

```
    usersSessions.forEach((session) -> {        
        sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(session.getId()).expireNow();
    });
```

Somethings to note

```
SessionInformation.expireNow()
```

is not mean to remove entries from the `redis` database, it just appends the expired attribute to session as you rightly mentioned.

**But how this invalidates the session of the user?**

Here comes the [ConcurrentSessionFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/ConcurrentSessionFilter.html) into play where
`.doFilter()` method does the trick of `automatically logging out`

Here is the snippet for **ConcurrentSessionFilter**

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    if (session != null) {
        SessionInformation info = sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(session
                .getId());

        if (info != null) {
            if (info.isExpired()) {
                // Expired - abort processing
                doLogout(request, response);

                String targetUrl = determineExpiredUrl(request, info);

                if (targetUrl != null) {
                    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);

                    return;
                }
                else {
                    response.getWriter().print(
                            "This session has been expired (possibly due to multiple concurrent "
                                    + "logins being attempted as the same user).");
                    response.flushBuffer();
                }

                return;
            }
            else {
                // Non-expired - update last request date/time
                sessionRegistry.refreshLastRequest(info.getSessionId());
            }
        }
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Cheers to that!

Comment: One issue I find with this approach is that the expired sessions are never removed from redis db.

Comment: @HeisenBerg there you go: spring.session.cleanup.cron.expression (system property)

Answer (score 2):

```
@Autowired
private RedisIndexedSessionRepository redisIndexedSessionRepository;

redisIndexedSessionRepository.findByPrincipalName('your@login').keySet().forEach(redisIndexedSessionRepository::deleteById);
```

Comment: Perhaps you can expand your answer explaining what that code does, and/or how things changed in 4 years since the question was asked.

Comment: Yeah, you should really include a context in which this answer exists and why it is better than the already accepted one.

Comment: This one actually solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
usersSessions.forEach((session) -> {        
        sessionRegistry.delete(session.getId());
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do one time thing in debugging process, you can just log into `redis_cli` and flush all Redis keys.

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "spring:session:index:org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME:bbb"
2) "spring:session:expirations:1558782600000"
3) "spring:session:expirations:1558783140000"
4) "spring:session:sessions:expires:953146bf-7300-4394-bbf0-bf606ff6b326"
5) "spring:session:expirations:1558782540000"
6) "spring:session:sessions:953146bf-7300-4394-bbf0-bf606ff6b326"
127.0.0.1:6379> FLUSHALL
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
(empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for delete key "redisTemplate.opsForValue().getOperations().delete(KEY);"

Comment: It has the same effect. Doesn't delete the key.

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally have a problem where the existing session objects are not compatible with the current code, usually after upgrading to a version that includes a newer Spring version. i.e. the `serialVersionUID` has changed.

In this case, you cannot use any of the session interfaces (and the answers above) as they will all attempt to de-serialize the object which cannot be done.

Instead you just go back to basics

```java
Set<String> sessionKeys = redisTemplate.keys("spring:session:*");
if (sessionKeys != null) {
    redisTemplate.delete(sessionKeys);
}
```

The key search `"spring:session:*"` will need to change if you have set a different `redisNameSpace` on `@EnableRedisHttpSession`